# I want to share an image that is within the application bundle on facebook without url using FBWebDialogs?

Tags: ios, facebook, image

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"The mechanic has done a fine job improving my vehicle…", @"name", @"Click below to download this awesome app for FREE and challenge me", @"description",iTunesLink, @"link", img, @"picture", nil];
                //step 2
                // Invoke the dialog
                [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil parameters:params handler:
                 ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                     if (error) {
                         // Error launching the dialog or publishing a story.
                         //nslog(@"Error publishing story.");
                     } else
                     {
                         if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted)
                         {
                             // User clicked the "x" icon
                             //nslog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             // Handle the publish feed callback
                             NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                             if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"])
                             {
                                 // User clicked the Cancel button
                                 //nslog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
                             } else
                             {
                                 // User clicked the Share button
                                 //NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Posted story, id: %@", [urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]];
                                 // Show the result in an alert

                                 isSharedButtonTapped = YES;
                                 self.btnFacebookShare.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

                                 [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"Successfully shared to Facebook" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }];
```

If I'm providing the picture as "URL" its posting fine. Else its throwing error. I want to post an image that is within the application bundle. Can some on tell me where I'm coding wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 `NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"Sharing Tutorial", @"name",
                           @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
                           @"Allow your users to share stories on Facebook from your app using the iOS SDK.", @"description",
                           @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/", @"link",
                           @"http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png", @"picture",
                           nil];`   
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams:params
                           clientState:nil
                               handler:^(FBAppCall *call,
                                         NSDictionary *results,
                                         NSError *error) {
                                 if (error) {

                                 } else {
```

//share successdialog

```
                                 }
                            }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
 UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

FBPhotoParams *params = [[FBPhotoParams alloc] init];

// Note that params.photos can be an array of images.  In this example
// we only use a single image, wrapped in an array.
params.photos = @[img];

[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams:params
                               clientState:nil
                                   handler:^(FBAppCall *call,
                                             NSDictionary *results,
                                             NSError *error) {
                                     if (error) {
                                       NSLog(@"Error: %@",
                                             error.description);
                                     } else {
                                       NSLog(@"Success!");
                                     }
                                }];
}
```

For more details you can [check here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share#show-photo-share-dialog).

However this will add the shared image to Photos which would not be the way you want it to be. It will create a folder with the name of the app and the image will be added under this.